# Ansible: How to obtain a list of Windows services along with their current status?

Tags: json, ansible, ansible-facts

I am looking to get list of Windows services that is running along with their state by using [`win_service_info` module – Gather information about Windows services](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_service_info_module.html).

```yaml
---
- name: Service Status
  hosts: test
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
  
  - name: Create variable with services
    set_fact: 
      service_names: []

  - name: Get service info
    ansible.windows.win_service_info:
      name: USRJOB*
    register: service_info

  - name: Load variable
    set_fact:
      service_names: "{{ service_names }}" + {{ item }}
    loop: "{{ service_info | community.general.json_query('services[*].name') }}"
    
  - name: Print the Countries after adding element
    debug: var=service_names
```

I couldn't load the variable `service_names` with all the services, no idea on how to also show the state of the service on the same debug message.

Comment: Can you share the content of `service_info`? Or provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

just change the third task to:

```
  - name: Load variable
    set_fact:
      service_names: "{{ service_names  + [ item ] }}"
    loop: "{{ service_info | community.general.json_query('services[*].name') }}"
```

Edit:

and if you want the state too, so you can change this task to:

```
  - name: Load variable
    set_fact:
      service_names: "{{ service_names  + [ item.name ~ ':' ~ item.state ] }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ service_info.services }}"
```